# Why is there no "first greater/less than [or equal to]" comparison operator in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am considering the proposal of 4 new comparison operators in SQL. These are similar to the `>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=` operators, but are true only if the value of each operand is, among all values satisfying the inequality, the one **closest** to the value of the other operand. Since one value is almost **at** the other value, I have come to the conclusion (after realizing that there is no `first` keyword, and after discarding the `unique` keyword) that a good choice would be to define these 4 new operators:

- `a @> b` : true if `a > b` and no `a' < a` satisfies `a' > b` and no `b' > b` satisfies `a > b'`
- `a @< b` : true if `b @> a`
- `a @>= b` : true if `a ≥ b` and no `a' < a` satisfies `a' ≥ b` and no `b' > b` satisfies `a ≥ b'`
- `a @<= b` : true if `b @>= a`

The question is: **is there some good reason why operators like these don't exist already?**

---

(2014-03-20) I reformulate the question, because the above formulation apparently isn't clear enough:

**Is there a reason why operators like these should not exist?**

---

The following examples are intended as a starting point for finding out where the problems with the `@...` operators could lie. I will use 3 MySQL tables:

```
create table ta (id int auto_increment, ca char, primary key(id), unique index(ca));
create table tb (id int auto_increment, cb char, primary key(id), index(cb));
create table tc (id int auto_increment, cc char, primary key(id));
insert into ta (ca) values ('A'),('E'),('I'),('O'),('U');
insert into tb (cb) values ('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('F'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('Z');
insert into tc (cc) values ('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('F'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('Z');
```

#### Example #1

When columns have unique values, the effect of the `@...` operators can be obtained by limiting the output of queries or subqueries to 1 row, although with a somewhat more clumsy syntax:

```
?> select * from ta where ca @> 'B'; -- currently not valid, equivalent to:
!> select * from ta where ca > 'B' order by ca limit 1;
+----+------+
| id | ca   |
+----+------+
|  2 | E    |
+----+------+
```

(`limit 1` is specific to MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, etc., other RDBMSs have `select top 1`, `where rownum = 1`, etc.)

In table `ta` we have a unique index on column `ca`. This index can be exploited to get to the selected value **at the same speed** as for `ca = 'E'`. The optimizer may realize this, but if it doesn't, data structures may be set up for an unneeded scan starting at the selected value (MySQL's `explain` says that this is a `range` type query).

#### Example #2

When columns have non-unique values, limiting output rows is useless, and the syntax becomes even more clumsy:

```
?> select * from tb where cb @> 'E'; -- currently not valid, equivalent to:
!> select * from tb where cb = (select min(cb) from tb where cb > 'E');
+----+------+
| id | cb   |
+----+------+
|  4 | F    |
|  5 | F    |
+----+------+
```

Luckily, if I correctly read the output of `explain`, MySQL is smart enough to optimize the subquery away, but if it weren't, the index would be used twice instead of once.

In the case of the table `tc`, which has no index on column `cc`, MySQL makes two table scans. This is understandable, since a single table scan would mean using an unknown amount of storage for the temporary result.

#### Example #3

Suppose you need all pairs consisting of a value and its successor value:

```
?> select t1.ca as c1, t2.ca as c2
   from ta t1
   join ta t2 on t1.ca @< t2.ca; -- currently not valid, equivalent to:
!> select t1.ca as c1, t2.ca as c2
   from ta t1
   join ta t2 on t2.ca = (select min(ca) from ta where ca > t1.ca);
+------+------+
| c1   | c2   |
+------+------+
| A    | E    |
| E    | I    |
| I    | O    |
| O    | U    |
+------+------+
```

If I read the output of `explain` correctly, the MySQL optimizer is not able to do without the correlated subquery, while we humans would know better. Maybe with the help of special handling of the `@...` operators wired in, the optimizer would do a single scan?

#### Example #4

This is similar, but across two tables, one of which has a non-unique index:

```
?> select * from ta join tb on ca @< cb; -- currently not valid, equivalent to:
!> select * from ta join tb on cb = (select min(cb) from tb where cb > ca);
+----+------+----+------+
| id | ca   | id | cb   |
+----+------+----+------+
|  1 | A    |  1 | C    |
|  2 | E    |  4 | F    |
|  2 | E    |  5 | F    |
|  3 | I    |  6 | M    |
|  4 | O    |  9 | Z    |
|  5 | U    |  9 | Z    |
+----+------+----+------+
```

Here too, the MySQL optimizer does not optimize away the subquery, although (maybe with a hint by the `@<`) it could.

#### Example #5

(Added on 2014-03-20.) The `@...` operators seem to make sense wherever their `@`-less counterparts do. Here is a contrived example of an expression in a `where` condition:

```
?> select * from ta join tb
   where round((ascii(ca)+ascii(cb))/2) @> ascii('E');
   -- currently not valid, equivalent to:
!> select * from ta join tb
   where round((ascii(ca)+ascii(cb))/2) = (
      select min(round((ascii(ca)+ascii(cb))/2)) from ta, tb
      where      round((ascii(ca)+ascii(cb))/2) > ascii('E')
   );
+----+------+----+------+
| id | ca   | id | cb   |
+----+------+----+------+
|  3 | I    |  1 | C    |
|  2 | E    |  4 | F    |
|  2 | E    |  5 | F    |
+----+------+----+------+
```

#### Example #6

... and this is another example, this time of a `select` expression:

```
?> select *, cb @< ca
   from tb, ta; -- currently not valid, equivalent to:
!> select *, ifnull(cb = (select max(cb) from tb where cb < ca), 0) as 'cb @< ca'
   from tb, ta;
+----+------+----+------+----------+
| id | cb   | id | ca   | cb @< ca |
+----+------+----+------+----------+
|  1 | C    |  1 | A    |        0 |
|  1 | C    |  2 | E    |        0 |
|  1 | C    |  3 | I    |        0 |
|  1 | C    |  4 | O    |        0 |
|  1 | C    |  5 | U    |        0 |
|  2 | D    |  1 | A    |        0 |
|  2 | D    |  2 | E    |        1 |
| -- (omitting rows with cb @< ca equal to 0 from here on)
|  4 | F    |  3 | I    |        1 |
|  5 | F    |  3 | I    |        1 |
|  7 | N    |  4 | O    |        1 |
|  8 | O    |  5 | U    |        1 |
```

---

I am aware of the following caveats:

#### Caveat #1

The `@...` operators are "non-local", because they need the knowledge of all possible values of their operands. This seems not to be a problem in all conditions of the kinds shown in the above examples, but could be a problem in other places (although I haven't found an example yet that could not be solved by an additional subquery).

#### Caveat #2

The `@...` operators, unlike their `@`-less counterparts, are not transitive. They share this property with the `<>` operator, though.

#### Caveat #3

Fully exploiting the `@...` operators *could* mean introducing new index and table access types (as discussed in the examples).

---

Please note that this question is not meant as a starting point for a discussion. I am looking for the reasons why something like the `@...` operators is not in the standard nor in any SQL dialect known to me - I expect these reasons to be related to some problem with the definition and/or implementation of these operators that I have overlooked.

I know that one reason is "Occam's razor" (*pluralitas non est ponenda sine necessitate*), but, as I have tried to show above, *pluralitas* here also brings some advantages (conciseness and ease of optimization). I am looking for stronger reasons.

---

(2014-03-31) `@>`, `@<`, `@>=` and `@<=` could become `|>`, `|<`, `|>=` and `|<=` or similar (read: first greater/less [equal]), in order not to collide with established usages of the `@` identifier prefix.

Comment: If you are adding functionality to MySQL, mightI suggest starting with the analytic functions?

Comment: One problem I can see with this approach is that the result of an expression depends on the context in which it is executed.

Comment: @nwellnhof, could be, but: columns come from tables, and all their values are accessible. Variables and constants only have one value. So where is the problem? Do you have a problematic example?

Comment: The question is entirely opinion-based. If you want to know why things aren't there that you expect, you would have to ask the inventors, and they did most of their work in the early 1970s so they may not be even with us. All you will get here is more or less uninformed opinion.

Comment: @EJP: it's not opinion-based. I have tried to make clear that I'm NOT asking why this kind of operators is not present in SQL, but whether there is some reason why they SHOULD not be.

Answer (score 12):

I am confused as to whether this is an appropriate forum for this question.  But, the reason these operators do not exist is that they are not particularly useful and other ANSI SQL functionality takes their place.

First, the comparison operators in the `on` clause are, in every database I know, available in the `where` and `case` clauses.  It is unclear how these operators would be used in these contexts.

Second, the operators don't specify what to do in the case of ties.  Return all rows?  But that would return multiple rows when the user of such an operator would expect only one row.

Third, ANSI standard functionality, such as `row_number()` can generate equivalent results.  Although it might not be as optimal for this particular problem, it is more general.  And standard.

By the way, Postgres has a nice capability with `distinct on()`, which is often more efficient than the analytic function equivalent.

I have secretly wanted a new `join` type, `lookup join`, that would fail if more than one record matched.  However, I'm not so sure that the entire language should be changed for this purpose.

Comment: I agree that the `@...` operators would not add functionality that does not already exist, but, as I have tried to show, they would add conciseness in some cases that are not infrequent (especially the comparison to a constant), and also, possibly, better and easier optimization. To your "First": correct - I have thought of that, but made no examples to keep the question short. Do you have a problematic example ready?. To your "Second": I think you have `limit 1` in mind, while I have not, my example #2 (and also the definition) should answer that. To your "Third": see your "Second" ;-)

Comment: @WalterTross . . . Shouldn't this discussion be on some MySQL forum?

Comment: Well, if it were a discussion, it would have to be on some forum (not necessarily MySQL!), but mine really is a question. I'm looking for the REAL problems these `@...` operators could have.

Answer (score 8):

Putting aside for a moment the merits of your proposed addition, you actually had only one question:

> The question is: is there some good reason why operators like these don't exist already?

The same reason for any other absent feature: **because no one implemented it yet.**

Now, the reason that no one implemented it is likely that no one felt a burning need to have a special operator for it, because of a combination of the following:

- The cases where it is useful are uncommon, and polluting a language with a new operator for every conceivable task is not a good idea.
- The workarounds to achieve the same task with existing syntax are easy and adequate.
- If people did feel the feature would be worth implementing, they might use a different syntax than one using `@` as part of the operators.

Being concise is great of course, but that doesn't seem to be the goal of SQL in general (otherwise SQL would be written in [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) notation).

Nonstandard clauses like `LIMIT`  (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite), or `TOP` (Microsoft, Sybase), or `ROWNUM` (Oracle), or `FIRST` (Informix, InterBase) suffice for most users.

Standard syntax using ordered window functions is in fact the solution defined by the SQL:2003 specification. I realize the window functions are [not supported by MySQL yet](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28957), but they are supported in virtually every other brand of RDBMS.

If you're proposing adding this functionality specifically for MySQL, it would be better to make it more compatible with other brands using standard syntax, rather than introduce new nonstandard syntax.

---

Now to your other question:

> I'm looking for the REAL problems these @... operators could have.

One comes to mind immediately: **it's not general-purpose.**

It handles the case where you want only the single row immediately following the comparison operand. But it doesn't handle many other cases that ordered window functions could satisfy:

- Return the next *two* rows in a window.
- Return the *last* row in a window.
- Return the top three rows by *rank* rather than by row number.
- etc.

It also introduces a new piece of punctuation that has no precedent in standard SQL, and which may conflict with some vendor additions, like prefixing user variables in MySQL or prefixing parameters in Microsoft SQL Server.

---

I tested your examples in PostgreSQL 8.4, which [supports window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html). I know that's not the current version of PostgreSQL, but it is the default version in the CentOS repo, and it's adequate to demonstrate window functions.

**Example #1**

```
select * 
from (select *, row_number() over (order by ca) as rn from ta where ca > 'B') as t
where rn = 1;

 id | ca | rn 
----+----+----
  2 | E  |  1
```

**Example #2**

```
select * 
from (select *, rank() over (order by cb) as rk from tb where cb > 'E') as t
where rk = 1;

 id | cb | rk 
----+----+----
  5 | F  |  1
  4 | F  |  1
```

**Example #3**

```
select t1.ca as c1, t2.ca as c2
from (select ca, row_number() over (order by ca) AS rn from ta) as t1
join (select ca, row_number() over (order by ca) AS rn from ta) as t2
  on t1.rn+1 = t2.rn;

 c1 | c2 
----+----
 A  | E
 E  | I
 I  | O
 O  | U
```

**Example #4**

```
select *
from (select ta.id, ta.ca, tb.id, tb.cb, 
    rank() over (partition by ca order by cb) AS rk 
    from ta join tb on ca < cb) as t
where rk = 1;

 id | ca | id | cb | rn 
----+----+----+----+----
  1 | A  |  1 | C  |  1
  2 | E  |  5 | F  |  1
  2 | E  |  4 | F  |  1
  3 | I  |  6 | M  |  1
  4 | O  |  9 | Z  |  1
  5 | U  |  9 | Z  |  1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm only _considering_ the proposal, and not necessarily for MySQL. I haven't encountered ordered window/analytical functions yet. They seem to fulfill other needs than what drove me my way (originally more performance than syntax). To make sure I understand: how would one (or more) of my examples be written using ordered window/analytical functions?

Comment: Bill, please don't take it personally, but I think that for these use cases the syntax is less user-friendly than that with the subquery, and I'm not able to see how this syntax would be more optimizer-friendly

Comment: Whether the optimizer can do anything to help depends on the optimizer code, not the syntax. My point is that for better or for worse, there *is* a SQL:2003 standard way to do these queries, even if you don't like their syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is not truly a question for somewhere like this. It does sound like a nice function, I must admit, but there are other ways of doing it. (Though I guess a lot of other functions have been added that had other ways f doing it too!)

I suppose the true answers to something like this could be something like:

**A. Demand -** Is it worth the developers time to add functions like this to SQL if they feel that very few people would use them?

**B. Functionality -** Does it actually allow the developer to DO MORE, or is it just another way of getting to the same goal?

**C. Laziness -** Can they actually be bothered to develop something like this?

The best way to get an answer to this would be to submit it to their development team and see what their response is, if enough people could get involved in asking for something like this to be implemented, then it could... power of the majority!